# Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, memcached, cakephp-1.3

We got the error in cakephp 1.3.6. version.No idea why and how,
please give your advice or solution.

error: Class 'AppController' not found....... in cakephp 1.3.6.

Thanks

Ajay

Comment: kindly check if there is AppController.php file in controller folder if not create one

Comment: create one AppController.php file under Controller folder.

Comment: All file are there.
Can you give me any suggestion related caching management in cakephp.
I am going to brief my query.Actually when we go some another controller it give error that controller not found but all file are exist there.

Comment: Try using this 
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); where ever you are getting AppController not found error. if App::uses does not work try App::import

Comment: You don't provide much information here. When do you get this error? Which class is called? How does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller class , use at the top as 1st statement

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

Because you are extending AppController , so you first need to import it.Like below.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class CoursesController extends AppController {/*Your code*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone. For me it was a misplaced semicolon in a Cakephp find method which was written in the AppController itself. Cakephp went absolutely crazy and threw this weird error which made no sense. Here's the WRONG CODE which was causing the issue for me, notice the semicolon in the conditions array which was a typo on my part.

```
$user_data = $this->User->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.cookie' => $cookie_val;
        )
    )
);
```