# Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found error

Tags: php, cakephp

Can anyone tell me what might be the source of this error. I have tried all solutions I found online with no avail. I just installed a cakePHP framework and I am getting this error on index.cpt page...

Error:  Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in [mypath] on line 2

```
<?php
class HomeController extends AppController {
     function index() {
     //nothing's here
     }
 }
?>
```

The above is my code...homeController.php and appController.php are on the same folder

Comment: is [mypath] the place where it should be looking?  If it's not looking at the right path, then it's a config issue...if it's looking at the right path but not able to find the class, then you probably named the namespace or the class name incorrectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208551/fatal-error-class-appcontroller-not-found)

Comment: That's btw the first google result... also check **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem after many searching

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    class HomeController extends AppController{
        public function index(){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was getting

> Error: Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\App\Controller' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\CakePHP\src\Controller\TestsController.php on line 5

TestsController.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;

    class TestsController extends App**\**Controller {
        public function index() {
        }
    }
?>
```

Solution: The error was just a silly typing mistake in extends line. it was a "\",
in App\Controller; 
Using AppController instead of App\Controller has resolved the problem.